# Can I cancel a Delta flight within 24 hours of booking?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, delta-air-lines

I need to cancel my flight. How do I cancel the flight for free, if possible?

Comment: What class ticket have you got and when did you book?

Comment: Did you book directly from Delta, or from a third party like Expedia or Kiwi?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your ticket.

[Delta's cancellation policy](https://www.delta.com/us/en/change-cancel/cancel-flight) states where a cancellation fee doesn't apply. Since you booked less than 24 hours ago, you are eligible for **24-Hour Risk-Free Cancellation** if you booked on delta.com or the Fly Delta app.

What you will receive is based on your class of ticket:

> Main Cabin tickets and higher that are canceled prior to departure will retain the value of the ticket. Review your Basic Economy ticket to see if you are eligible to cancel your ticket prior to departure and receive an Credit.

The process for taking advantage of this offer can be found below:

> ## 24-Hour Risk-Free Cancellation Process
>
> - [Find Your Trip](https://www.delta.com/mytrips/) or [Log In](https://www.delta.com/login/loginPage?refreshURL=/us/en/change-cancel/cancel-flight?staticurl=t) and go to [My Trips](https://www.delta.com/mytrips/)
> - Select the trip you need to cancel
> - Select ‘Cancel Flight’ button and follow the steps
> - Receive a full refund, which will be automatically issued to your original form of payment

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that any flight purchased through a carrier (ie not through a third party reseller) in the US can be canceled within 24 hours. So you should be allowed to do that, if you bought from Delta.
https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Notice_24hour_hold_final20130530_0.pdf

Comment: If you are posting a link in the answer, it is recommended to also quote relevant portions of the text from there. This helps in case the link becomes unreachable in the future.